# downloadWindow = window.open(fileUrl); auto/force download/save file

Tags: javascript, download

I have following line of code :

```
downloadWindow = window.open(fileUrl);
```

How to make `window.open(fileUrl);` can automatically save/download file

I tried following

```
downloadWindow = window.open(fileUrl, '_self'); // do not work
downloadWindow = window.open(fileUrl, 'download'); // do not work to
downloadWindow = window.location(fileUrl, 'download'); // do not work
downloadWindow = window.location.href(fileUrl); // do not work
```

not work can auto save/download file,

I can not auto/force/directly save/download file without a popup

Comment: Most modern browsers will not auto save unless the user has set a specific setting in the browser which you cannot change programmatically

Comment: try serving the file online/server-side and then open the link, that may work for you.

Comment: It should be the server that specify if it should be a download or not using an attachment http header

Comment: thanks sir for reply.. how about htaccess can force auto download file pdf?